# For loop in useEffect too many re-renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a for loop that starts with 1 column at the window.innerHeight of 530px and increments with +1 if the window.innerHeight gets incremented with 40.

This is what I have right now, but it says too many re-renders everytime.
Does anyone know why?

```
let gridcolumns = 1;
  useEffect(() => {
    for (let i = 530; i < window.innerHeight; i += 40) {
      gridcolumns += 1;
    }
  });
  setColumnsAmount(gridcolumns);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add dependency list to your useEffect :

```
let gridcolumns = 1;
  useEffect(() => {
    for (let i = 530; i < window.innerHeight; i += 40) {
      gridcolumns += 1;
    }
  setColumnsAmount(gridcolumns);
  },[]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `useEffect` call has no dependency array, so its callback is called after **every** render. The callback then does `setColumnsAmount`, which triggers a re-render, which triggers the `useEffect` callback, which triggers a re-render, etc.

You need to specify a dependency array that says what it is that needs to change to make you want to run the callback, or don't use `useEffect` for this at all and do the `columnsAmount` change in an event callback (perhaps a `resize` event).

---

Side note: You can probably replace the `for` loop with `const x = Math.floor(window.innerHeight / 40);` and then doing whatever it is you want to with `x` (for instance, you could add it to `gridColumns` if that's really the right thing).